# How do I redirect stdin/stdout when I have a sequence of commands in Bash?

Tags: python, bash, pipe, subprocess

I've currently got a Bash command being executed (via Python's `subprocess.Popen`) which is reading from `stdin`, doing something and outputing to `stdout`.  Something along the lines of:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen( ["-c", "cmd1 | cmd2"],
                       stdin = subprocess.PIPE, 
                       stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell =True )
output_data = pid.communicate( "input data\n" )
```

Now, what I want to do is to change that to execute another command in that same subshell that will alter the state before the next commands execute, so my shell command line will now (conceptually) be:

```
cmd0; cmd1 | cmd2
```

Is there any way to have the input sent to `cmd1` instead of `cmd0` in this scenario?  I'm assuming the output will include `cmd0`'s output (which will be empty) followed by `cmd2`'s output.

`cmd0` shouldn't actually read anything from `stdin`, does that make a difference in this situation?

I know this is probably just a dumb way of doing this, I'm trying to patch in `cmd0` without altering the other code too significantly.  That said, I'm open to suggestions if there's a much cleaner way to approach this.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking.  Maybe give a specific example or, better yet, describe what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

execute *cmd0* and *cmd1* in a subshell and redirect */dev/null* as *stdin* for cmd0:

```
(cmd0 </dev/null; cmd1) | cmd2
```

Comment: +1: though the OP said cmd0 won't touch stdin, good to be safe!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should have to do anything special. If cmd0 doesn't touch stdin, it'll be intact for cmd1. Try for yourself:

```
ls | ( echo "foo"; sed 's/^/input: /')
```

(Using `ls` as an arbitrary command to produce a few lines of input for the pipeline)

And the additional pipe to cmd2 doesn't affect the input either, of course.

Comment: Ok, that looks good and is what I needed to know.  Will try it out when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I may be able to duplicate the `stdin` file descriptor to a temporary one, close it, run `cmd0`, then restore it before running `cmd1`:

```
exec 0>&3; exec 0<&-; cmd0 ; exec 3>&0 ; cmd1 | cmd2
```

Not sure if it's possible to redirect `stdin` in this way though, and can't test this at the moment.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17601.html

Comment: ok, this is probably not necessary (even if it was going to work) given the other answers people have given.